How to show multiple sub-options in dropdown using Material UI?
I am trying to show nested options in a dropdown which on hovering should open up its sub-options and close sub-options on mouse leave. However, I am facing an issue where the sub-options open on onMouseEnter but close immediately when onMouseLeave is used.
I believe the issue might be with how I am handling setAnchorEl as null on close.
Expected Behavior:

On hovering over an option, its sub-options should open.
On mouse leave, the sub-options should close after a brief delay.

Current Issue:

When using only onMouseEnter, the sub-options open but don't close.
When using both onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave, the sub-options do not open at all.

const NestedDropdown: React.FC<NestedDropdownProps> = ({ name, label, options, watchFieldNames, onFieldChange }) => {
    const { control, setValue } = useFormContext();
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    const [nestedAnchorEl, setNestedAnchorEl] = useState<Record<string, HTMLElement | null>>({});
    const [hoveredOptionId, setHoveredOptionId] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [selectedOptionId, setSelectedOptionId] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [focusedOptionIndex, setFocusedOptionIndex] = useState<number>(0);
    const [clickedLabel, setClickedLabel] = useState<string | null>(null); // State to track clicked label

    const handleOpen = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        setNestedAnchorEl({});
        setHoveredOptionId(null);
        setClickedLabel(null);
    };

    const handleNestedOpen = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, optionId: string) => {
        console.log(`Opening nested popover for option ${optionId}`); // Debug log
        console.log(`Event target:`, event.currentTarget); // Debug log

        setNestedAnchorEl((prev) => {
            const updated = {
                ...prev,
                [optionId]: event.currentTarget,
            };
            console.log(`Updated nestedAnchorEl:`, updated); // Debug log
            return updated;
        });

        setHoveredOptionId(optionId);
    };

    const handleNestedClose = (optionId: string) => {
        console.log(`Closing nested popover for option ${optionId}`); // Debug log

        setNestedAnchorEl((prev) => {
            const updated = {
                ...prev,
                [optionId]: null,
            };
            console.log(`Updated nestedAnchorEl:`, updated); // Debug log
            return updated;
        });

        setHoveredOptionId(null);
    };

    const handleOptionMouseEnter = (optionId: string, event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        console.log(`Mouse entered option ${optionId}`);
        console.log(`Current nestedAnchorEl for ${optionId}:`, nestedAnchorEl[optionId]);

        if (!(optionId in nestedAnchorEl) || nestedAnchorEl[optionId] == null) {
            handleNestedOpen(event, optionId);
        }
    };

    const handleOptionMouseLeave = (optionId: string) => {
        console.log(`Mouse left option ${optionId}`);
        console.log(`Current nestedAnchorEl for ${optionId}:`, nestedAnchorEl[optionId]);

        if (optionId in nestedAnchorEl && nestedAnchorEl[optionId] != null) {
            handleNestedClose(optionId);
        }
    };

    const handleSelect = (id: string) => {
        setValue(name, id);
        setSelectedOptionId(id);
        handleClose();
        if (onFieldChange) {
            onFieldChange();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (anchorEl && options.length > 0) {
            setFocusedOptionIndex(0); // Focus first option when dropdown opens
        }
    }, [anchorEl, options]);

    const handleLabelClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setClickedLabel(label);
        handleOpen(e);
    };

    const handleOptionClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, option: NestedReportCategoryFilterType) => {
        setClickedLabel(label);
        handleSelect(option.item_category.id);
        handleClose();
    };

    const renderOptions = (options: NestedReportCategoryFilterType[]) => (
        <List style={{ padding: 0 }}>
            {options.map((option) => (
                <div key={option.item_category.id}>
                    <ListItem
                        button
                        onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e, option)}
                        onMouseEnter={(e) => handleOptionMouseEnter(option.item_category.id, e)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => handleOptionMouseLeave(option.item_category.id)}
                        style={{
                            minHeight: 30,
                            minWidth: 120,
                            border: `1px solid ${selectedOptionId === option.item_category.id ? "#f28c8c" : "#aaa"}`, // Light red/orange border
                            borderRadius: "4px",
                            marginBottom: 0,
                            fontSize: "8px", // Smaller font size for options
                            fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif", // Arial font for options
                            padding: 0,
                            backgroundColor: hoveredOptionId === option.item_category.id ? "#e0e0e0" : "transparent", // Light gray when hovered
                            color: selectedOptionId === option.item_category.id ? "black" : "inherit",
                        }}
                        tabIndex={0}
                    >
                        <ListItemText
                            primary={option.item_category.value}
                            style={{ padding: "0 8px", fontSize: "8px", fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif" }}
                        />
                        {option.item_category.subOptions && option.item_category.subOptions.length > 0 && (
                            <ListItemIcon style={{ minWidth: "auto", marginLeft: "auto" }}>
                                {nestedAnchorEl[option.item_category.id] ? (
                                    <ExpandMoreIcon fontSize="medium" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
                                ) : (
                                    <ArrowForwardIos fontSize="small" style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
                                )}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                        )}
                    </ListItem>
                    {option.item_category.subOptions && option.item_category.subOptions.length > 0 && nestedAnchorEl[option.item_category.id] && (
                        <Popover
                            open={Boolean(nestedAnchorEl[option.item_category.id])}
                            anchorEl={nestedAnchorEl[option.item_category.id]}
                            anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: "top",
                                horizontal: "right",
                            }}
                            transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: "top",
                                horizontal: "left",
                            }}
                            style={{
                                maxHeight: 500,
                                overflowY: "auto",
                                minWidth: 120,
                                borderRadius: "4px",
                                fontSize: "10px",
                            }}
                        >
                            <div style={{ maxHeight: 200, overflowY: "auto", minWidth: 120 }}>{renderOptions(option.item_category.subOptions)}</div>
                        </Popover>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </List>
    );

What could be causing the sub-options to not open when both onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are used?
How can I correctly handle the closing of sub-options with a brief delay?
